# How to tell if neural network is overfitting in Scikit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am training a neural network on Jupyter, using Sklearn and am having trouble with knowing when/if my network is overfitting the data. Right now I am plotting the actual outputs of my testing data vs the predicted outputs of the testing data my ANN came up with. Can anyone let me know if there is a specific way to tell?

This is what I am training on, and using around 1500 iterations, and 2 hidden layers with 6-8 nodes in each. My dataset has about 300 points, with 5 inputs and 2 outputs.

```
HiddenLayerStruture = (6,6)    
MaxNumEpochs = 1500
NN = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=HiddenLayerStruture,
                  activation='tanh',
                  solver='lbfgs',
                  alpha=0.0001,
                  learning_rate='constant',
                  max_iter=MaxNumEpochs)

NN.fit(Input_Trn_Scaled, Output_Trn_Scaled)
Output_Predicted_Scaled = NN.predict(Input_Tst_Scaled)
```

Thanks for any guidance that can be offered:)

Comment: You may want to look at the accuracy of your training_data, and then check the accuracy of your testing_data. If the testing_data accuracy is higher there is a good chance its overfitting - not a guarantee, just an indication